Cosmetic work on cement repairs
I recently had foundation work completed on my house (no issues) but they had to break through a few sites on my concrete porch and patio. They patched the sites with cement adequately but, as they were not finishers, these locations are rough and unsightly. What are my DIY (or pro) options to better cosmetically blend/hide these sites now that they are fully cured?
Edit: pics added



Rent a concrete grinder and smooth down the new patches into the old surfaces. Then cover with an epoxy concrete paint or put down a chattahoochee surface.

the little pebble epoxy surfaces look good.  certainly better than the patch work there or even if the patch happened to match the pebble epoxy would dress it up quite a bit !

Another option is to put down pressure treated sleepers and then do composite or standard decking overtop.

Had to google "chattahoochee surface". Learn something every day!

Huh.  Never heard exposed aggregate finish called "chattahoochee" before.  I guess I learned something too.

@Huesmann , gnicko   It's really popular down here, especially around pools. Use more epoxy than directions call for for a smoother surface.

@JACK I don't doubt it's popular—I see it everywhere, especially since I live in the DC area and the feds use it on basically all the sidewalks.  It's just I never heard it called chattahoochee before.
